# Escaping in nginx .conf

Tags: nginx

I am struggling with escaping the following string in ngnix, if someone can help that would be much appreciated.

```
 proxy_pass http://localhost:5820/IntegrationHub/query?query="Construct {<https://data.elsevier.com/$request_uri> ?p ?o } Where {{<https://data.elsevier.com/$request_uri> ?p ?o .} UNION {graph ?g {{<http\
s://data.elsevier.com/$request_uri> ?p ?o .}}}}";
```

Comment: It may be preferable to include the actual URL unescaped first.

Comment: Not sure to understand, would please illustrate ?

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer escape everything *spaces*, `{` and `"`.

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:5820/IntegrationHub/query?query=\"Construct\ \{<https://data.elsevier.com/$request_uri>\ ?p\ ?o\}\ Where\ \{\{<https://data.elsevier.com/$request_uri>\ ?p\ ?o\}\ UNION\ \{graph\ ?g\ \{\{<https://data.elsevier.com/$request_uri>\ ?p\ ?o\}\}\}\}\";
```

In doing so, `nginx -t` validates the file.